# segment image using pixel coordinates matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

This question maybe pretty basic, so please bear with me. I have 4 pixel coordinats and an image. I want to segment the image part within this 4 points alone and make a new image. Can you please tell me the easiest way to do this?

Comment: might be relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165422/bare-with-me-isnt-a-thing-yet-its-used-all-over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `roipoly` using `r` and `c` inputs in addition to input image `I`.

Comment: thank you. so roipoly will create a new image for me automatically? So I will have the smaller image as output?

Comment: `roipoly` will create a binary mask for you. If you want a smaller image you'll have to define a **rectangle** region for croping. You can use the bounding box of the binary mask for that. Look at `imcrop` for the actual croping of an image.

Comment: I saw imcrop, but it once again creates a tool with which I can crop. Am trying to segment image by indexing. i.e I1 = I(1:500,1:200). something like this. But when I tried, it did not work. That is why I asked here.

Comment: I have 4 pixel points of the rectangle, diag1,diag2,diag3,diag4, say. How can I get the smaller image within these 4 points as output? automatically and not by using any tool.

Comment: my apologies @Shai. Got carried away by the first words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a coordinate list `xcoord` matching with `ycoord` and want to have the smallest square that contains your pixels:

```
myImage = rand(100)
xcoord = [12 16 22 82];
ycoord = [24 70 12 34];

mySegment = myImage(xcoord(min):xcoord(max),ycoord(min):ycoord(max))
```

Comment: why axis-aligned rectangle?

Comment: @Shai Because it is the only shape I could think of for which it is automatically defined whether something is 'between' the coordinates.